# How to use a QTimer only after a QThread is started

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qt-signals, qtimer

I would like to use a QTimer in my MainWindow application. The timer should start when the thread is started. I have tried:

**ct_thread.h**

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>

class CT_Thread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CT_Thread(QObject* parent = 0);
    QTimer* timer;
    void run();

private slots:
    void on_timer();
};
```

**ct_thread.cpp** *(Version 1)*

```
#include "ct_thread.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QDebug>

CT_Thread::CT_Thread(QObject* parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{}

void CT_Thread::run()
{
    timer = new QTimer(0);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(on_timer()));
    timer->start(1000);

    // do something else
}

void CT_Thread::on_timer()
{
    qDebug() << "Hello World!";
}
```

This does not reach the "Hello World!", i.e. the connection does not work properly.

Alternatively, I tried connecting in the constructor. This connects the Slot but the timer starts when opening the GUI and not when the user starts *ct_thread*.

**ct_thread.cpp** *(Version 2)*

```
CT_Thread::CT_Thread(QObject* parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    timer = new QTimer(0);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(on_timer()));
    timer->start(1000);
}

void CT_Thread::run()
{
    
    // do something else
}

void CT_Thread::on_timer()
{
    qDebug() << "Hello World!";
}
```

What do I do wrong and how do I have to phrase it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this work: define signal-slot in constructor, initialize timer in constructor, then in run() call timer->start(1000)?

Comment: @kiner_shah thanks for answering. No it doesn't and the output says: "QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread".

Comment: How about just defining signal-slot in constructor. Initializing timer and calling its start method in run()?

Comment: @kiner_shah this does not work because connecting would happen before constructing with ```new```. This results in memory violation.

Comment: Your approach does not work, because of Thread Affinity. Check this question, its links and answer for some insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931492/confusion-regarding-qthread-qobject-thread-affinity-and-event-loop

Comment: @king_nak so if i interpret that correctly, you suggest that a call the timer from ```mainwindow.cpp``` because running inside of ```ct_thread->run()``` it would not work?

Comment: You have to decide in which thread you want to react to the timeout. This thread must run an event loop. As I don't know your case, I cannot give you a definitive answer. But generally, if you need post-thread signal processing, then you don't subclass QThread, but instead create objects and move them there; the default QThread::run simply runs a event loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the timer should be handled within the thread.

You are missing an event loop in the thread. QThread can be implemented with or without event loop. A timer needs an event loop (it cannot just interrupt the code it currently executes in the thread and call the `on_timer()` method preemtively instead).

Calling [`exec()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html#exec) will run the event loop for the thread.

```
void CT_Thread::run()
{
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(on_timer()));
    timer->start(1000);

    // do something else
    exec();
}
```

Note that I also gave the timer a parent to avoid a memory leak.

Note that a timer can also signal an event cross thread ([thread affinity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity) matters for that case). By default the thread affinity is the thread that created the object, therefore in your first example, the timer has the tread affinity set to the CT_Thread instance and will post it's event on the thread's event loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to connect the private signal `void QThread::started()` ( https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html#started) to a slot of your `CT_Thread` class. From there you can start your `QTimer`.